# I have an error : Cannot find module './utils'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setting up my node js server and I have this error when I run this command `npm run dev`:

```js
Error: Cannot find module './utils'
Require stack:
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/braces/lib/stringify.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/braces/index.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/chokidar/index.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/watch.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/index.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/lib/nodemon.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/lib/index.js
- /home/guesswl/www/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you provide more information and share some of the code where the error occurs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try delete > node_modules > npm install
Or something wrong with node version.

Comment: Can you please support with upvote or mark as answered?

Comment: I wonder how simply delete the node_modules can be a real solution

Comment: This worked for me. I hit ctrl-c almost immediately after running `npm install` because I forgot something.  I think that messed stuff up.  Deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install` a second time worked.  THANKS!

Comment: deleting  node_modules and running `npm install` and then `npm run build`  worked