# cannot find module in node express

Tags: javascript, express, npm

cannot find module in node express

Actual code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

error code in cmd

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>npm express -v

```
7.5.3
```

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>npm utils -v

```
7.5.3
```

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>node server

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './utils'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\qs\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\stringify.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\middleware\\query.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\application.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\express.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\node_modules\\express\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you installed express globally? `npm i -g express`? Or locally? `npm i express`?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee globally

Comment: I guess that is what is causing the problem, not sure though. And is there a solid reason why you're installing it globally, express is meant to be installed locally. Try installing it locally.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee tried it not working

Comment: This may help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438874/i-have-an-error-cannot-find-module-utils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

Download utils https://www.npmjs.com/package/utils

this is the error

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>
node server

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'utils'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\server.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\server.js' ]
}
```

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>
npm i utils

```
added 43 packages, removed 2 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 110 packages in 16s

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>node server
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
^C
```

C:\Users\user\Desktop\project>

Answer (score 0):

first try to remove the globally installed express

then initialize a `package.json` file with `npm init`. Here you will have a list of your dependencies, scripts and name of your package and some other data.

Then install express with `npm i express`.

after installing try to run it with `node server.js` or `npm start` if you have written the script to run the `start` command in `package.json`